# Batch Editing in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm using Flask-Admin and I want to be able to update many fields at once from the list view. It seemed like what I'm looking for is a custom action.

I was able to make it work, but I suspect not in the best way. I'm wondering if it could be done more "Flask"-ily.

What I do now, for example if I was updating all rows in table `cars` to have `tires = 4`:

- A custom action in the `CarView` class collects the ids of the rows to be modified, a callback url from `request.referrer`, and the tablename `cars`, and returns `render_template(mass_update_info.html)` with these as parameters.
- `mass_update_info.html` is an HTML form where the user specifies 1) the field they would like to change and 2) the value to change it to. On submit, the form makes a POST to a a certain view (`do_mass_update`) with this data (everything else is passed as hidden fields in this form).
- `do_mass_update` uses the data sent to it to construct a SQL query string -- in its entirety, `"UPDATE {} SET {}='{}' WHERE id IN ({})".format(table, column, value, ids)` -- which is run via `db.engine.execute()`.
- The user is redirected to the callback url.

It bothers me that I don't seem to be using any of SQLAlchemy, but (from a newbie's perspective) it all seems to be based on the model objects e.g. `User.query(...)`, while I only have access to the model/table name as a string. Can I get some kind of identifier from the model, pass that through, and do a lookup to retrieve the on the other side?

Comment: This sounds about right. I'd use dynamic query builder instead of string concatenation though. See here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update